How to solve the error "Graphics Device initialization failed for : d3d, sw - Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found"
I am using a player in my Java project but when I bring the library Javafx 11 in the lib folder of the Java Me Mudra project that error, the curious thing is that if I have the releases in another folder folder if it works.
Only in my case I need to be in the project lib of the project.
Some would know how to solve it
Thanks if time!
Solo espero que funcione
may 24, 2024 10:49:08 A.�M. com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @66048bfd'
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:283)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:253)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:268)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:291)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163)
    at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.lambda$initFx$1(JFXPanel.java:230)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:95)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    ... 1 more
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:280)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:291)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:163)
at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.lambda$initFx$1(JFXPanel.java:230)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)


You are missing JavaFX native components.
Either:

Follow instructions in getting started at openjfx.io.

Those instructions let you know how to get the JavaFX code on the module path AND have the location of the native libraries for JavaFX resolved, so they can BOTH be loaded.
See the IDE sections for development.
See the runtime images section for deployment.


OR use a JDK or JRE that includes JavaFX.

Azul and BellSoft provide them if you choose the right versions ("JDK FX" or "Full JDK").


OR use Maven artifacts for JavaFX.

Those include JavaFX native components, unlike the jars in the SDK which has native components separate from the jars.



You need to ensure you have the right native components for your architecture (e.g. mac M series are different from Mac Intel, Linux is different from Windows, etc.).
You need the appropriate hardware, OS libraries and graphics drivers to support JavaFX’s rendering, but it is highly likely you have all of those things and don’t need to worry about that.
If this answer is insufficient, then there are (currently) 111 duplicates on StackOverflow you could consider, though many are unanswered or provide misleading info.
